# Copy videofile while MediaRecorder is still recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder

How to copy and "finalize" the video file while MediaRecorder is recording? Actually I can copy the file to other location on sim-card - but it is "corrupted" ("Video can't be played because the file is corrupted") After the MediaRecorder is stopped (the video recording is finished) - I copy the file and it is "valid".

I guess the video file has no "close" markers while MediaRecorder is recording? How to "finalize" the video file? (.H264?) Or what media format (different from .H264) can be "viewable" on partial read video file?

```
mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
        .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("test.mp4");
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Comment: Have you Found a Solution for this ?